# Updating rows SQL Database from python iteration

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-update

I need help on updating the rows of values in SQL Database with the data that I got from python loop.

```
query = """ select P_PUL from Access.M_PWA """

cursor.execute(query)
dtbs= cursor.fetchall()
row_list=[]
ln = len(dtbs)
```

Then, I am not sure on what to do, I tried this code but does not work.

```
for line in query:
    query_update="""UPDATE Access.M_PWA SET P_PUL = ? """
    cursor.execute(query_update, line)

for i in range(ln):
    row=cursor.fetchval()
    result=slicing_bin(row)
    result_float = [float("{0:.2f}".format(i)) for i in result]
    row_list.append(result_float)
```

So, I want to update the P_PUL column and replace with the row_list values. Could anyone help me ? 
I tried to execute this code but I got some errors like:

> File
>   "C:/Users/ranic/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/Finalcombined.py",
>   line 64, in 
>       cursor.execute(query_update, line) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max)
>   is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (257)
>   (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsof

Thank you in advance! As i am new to python, i Hope someone could help.

Comment: Unrelated to the error you are getting: don't you need a `WHERE` clause in the query? As it is, *each* iteration of the loop will blindly update `P_PUL` in *all* records of `Access.M_PWA`.

Comment: Thanks! So the where clause is like the primary key that differentiate each row, right? As I dont have the id, I can only use date time `(2015-02-21 14:00:03)` , do you think thats okay?
So, it becomes 
`query_update="""UPDATE Access.dbo.M_PWA SET P_PULSES = ? WHERE DATETIME=?"""`

Comment: Ideally you should be using the primary key of the table, whatever that is (could be a single column or a combination of columns).

Comment: But again, while this fixes some logic issue, this will not resolve the error that you are currently getting. Did you try to use the `CONVERT` function, as suggested in the error message, to turn your `nvarchar` to a binary datatype?

Comment: the original data in the SQL is in HEX string, something like 0x9406920691.. and i want to update it as an integer and to be like 1940,1980. I am not sure what to do next, the plan is to update the sql to get the data in .txt.

Comment: can I change binary(max) and update it with varchar?